# TBitmapLink.SourceRect.Top Error on Application Create (REST)

Tags: rest, delphi, server, datasnap

I have a REST client that runs in my machine and used to run in a server.

Now I opened my project and changed ONLY the username and password in my FDConnection and I get this error on application startup (before any lines of code are run):

"Exception EReadError in module xxx.exe at 000C3018.
Error reading TActiveStyleObject.ActiveLink: Error reading TBitmapLink.SourceRect.Top: Invalid floating point operation.

Does anybody have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Before any code executed? You sure? Have you got a stack trace? What debugging have you done?

Comment: this only happens outside of my machine;

Comment: I added a showmessage before the code delphi generates when u create the REST project:
if WebRequestHandler <> nil then
    WebRequestHandler.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;

Comment: am remaking the project and keeping my ServerMethods unit to see if it works.

Comment: omg not even that worked I think there's something wrong with my server

Comment: You need to add some trace logging

Comment: File was getting corrupted for some reason